# Birthday message — "from" or "by"?

Tags: prepositions, word-difference

Someone recorded a happy birthday message on a video.. I want to show his video to a public, which would be correct?

Happy Birthday message **from** FirstName LastName

Happy Birthday message **by** FirstName LastName

Comment: *message from*, *video by* period! And if both are the same, the choice is yours. :P

Comment: The message is **FROM** you to the recipient

Answer (score 2):

In "**by person**", the person is the one who recorded (created) the video. In "**from person**", the person is the one who is wishing happy birthday.

To write it correctly, you can write "Happy Birthday message **from** person A and person B **by** (created by) person A,"  but it will be better to use just the **from** part.

Comment: what if creator and sentence-teller is the same?

Comment: In that case, I think using just "from" in the sentence is fine. "by" will be required only when we intend to give special credits to the one who made the video.

Answer (score 0):

"Message from" is correct. Because here the person giving the message isn't a subject of the sentence.